# Pick Three Numbers

Tags: probability

Let's say a bucket is filled with the numbers zero through nine. We shake up the bucket, reach into it, and grab three numbers. We picked 7,3,8. If we would've picked 7,3,9 we would've won cotton candy. Now we put the numbers back into the bucket, shake it up, and grab three numbers again...

My question: *is this just a simple game of chance or can some math skillz be applied to win the game?* Obviously I'm not a math genius, so please reply in laymen's terms :)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no strategy to win this game, since you have no control on it. By the description you give, it is clear that one cannot take any decision: all you can do is grabbing numbers until you win.

Comment: You could compute the probability of your winning, but that won't help your odds..

Comment: How many efforts do you have available? This will not affect the odds of you winning, but it might save you time for something more engaging than shaking buckets all day!